# If the potential shifts by $a$ in x axis, would the Wave function shift by $a$ as well?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

While solving problems in QM I had the following question in mind. If the solution is found to be $\psi(x)$ for the original potential $V(x)$ in the time independent Scrödinger equation, would it be transformed to $\psi(x-a)$ if the potential is shifted to $V(x-a)$? It seemed like for the infinite square well, if I switch the well's ends be located at $x=0$ and $x=a$ to $x=\frac{a}{2}$ and $x=-\frac{a}{2}$ I just need to shift the original wave function by $\frac{a}{2}$ to get the new wave function. Can I apply this to other cases as well?

Comment: Just plug into Schrodinger's equation and see if it works

Comment: I notice this has picked up a close vote, but I don't think it's the kind of question that needs to be closed as being homework-like. It seems more like a conceptual question that arose in the context of a homework or educational problem, it's not asking for the solution to a homework question itself.